# Tramp and Dired: Initial default-directory/dired-directory

Tags: dired, tramp

I'm trying to use tabbar to setup groups for each remote host where I have buffers open. I need to get the full buffer name, so I can parse the hostname to set the group name.

I've figured out how to do everything I want, except for when using tramp and dired.

When I initially open /ssh:dev:/home/fandingo/, I get some strange values for `dired-directory` and `default-directory`:

```
 (default-directory .
   #("/ssh:fandingo@dev:/home/fandingo/" 5 12
     (tramp-default t)))

 (dired-directory .
                  #("/ssh:fandingo@dev:/home/fandingo/" 5 12
                    (tramp-default t)))
```

(I used `M-x pp-eval-expression RET (buffer-local-variables) RET` to get this info.)

If I navigate to a directory within this buffer (say elisp/), these variables become "normal:"

```
 (default-directory . "/ssh:fandingo@dev:/home/fandingo/elisp/")

 (dired-directory . "/ssh:fandingo@dev:/home/fandingo/elisp/")
```

If I go up (..) to the original directory, things go back to the weird values.

**What variable or function can I use to consistently get the full tramp path, regardless of whether I've navigated anywhere or not in the dired buffer?**

Alternatively, how can I transparently handle both data structures to get the tramp path? I'm not sure I even understand what Emacs is returning in the originally visited directory (It's not a list, or at least I couldn't `car` it.).

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.16.6)

Comment: Here is a related thread to test for a particular remote host:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24481381/emacs-dired-mode-test-to-determine-remote-server-name-address

Comment: The form `#("/ssh:fandingo@dev:/home/fandingo/" 5 12 (tramp-default t))` is how Emacs writes a string that has text properties. This is just the string `"/ssh:fandingo@dev:/home/fandingo/"`, but with text property `tramp-default` with value `t`. You can use that string anywhere, as an ordinary string. This is just the way Emacs prints the value of a propertized string.

Comment: Wrt having different remote directories set up ahead of time: Instead of using tab bar for this, consider using **bookmarks**. You can bookmark a Dired buffer, including one for a remote directory. "Jumping" to a Dired bookmark just opens Dired on that directory.

Comment: Wow, elisp continues to blow me away. That's really cool. Thanks for the info @Drew!

Comment: Emacs strings can be pretty cool. Just as symbols have a property list, where you can store any info you like, the same is true of Emacs-Lisp strings. Both Lisp symbols and Emacs-Lisp strings are objects of a sort. An odd feature, especially for strings, but one that can actually be pretty handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Drew wrote, you see strings with text properties. If you worry about, use `(substring-no-properties default-directory)` and `(substring-no-properties dired-directory)`

Comment: That's really neat. Thanks for the info1